# str_replace() doesn't replace needle in a Chinese string

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding, str-replace

I have a few languages in my site but the code below doesn't work for Chinese language. Every other text appear on the screen so there no problem with output. I wonder if str_replace() becomes allergic to %s when used in Chinese texts! Only replacing %s doesn't work.

Note: %(any char doesn't matter) doesn't work.

Any idea why?

Thanks

```
$lang = "％s的字段是必需的。";
echo $message = str_replace('%s', '123', $lang);
//Should output 123的字段是必需的。but instead ％s的字段是必需的。appears again.
echo $message = str_replace('的字段是必需的', '123', $lang);
//This outputs %s123. which is fine
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `%` is not a "proper" %. Look at this:

```
$lang = '%s的字段是必需的。';
```

instead of

```
$lang = '％s的字段是必需的。';
```

If you look closely at the two, you'll see that the "%" character is different.

So your string `$lang` has a `％` and your `str_replace` is looking for `%`.

Comment: I can't believe you noticed that. +1

Comment: Just for reference, "％" seems to be a "fullwidth percent sign": http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff05/index.htm